# How to perform batch update of a column within a range in psql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, psql

Here is my table structure:

```
Table name:Items
--------------------------------
 id   | category_id |  code   |
--------------------------------
 1   | 1            |  15156  |
 2   | 1            |  15157  |
 2   | 1            |  15158  |
 2   | 1            |  15159  |
 2   | 1            |  15160  |
 2   | 1            |  15161  |
```

Here code field is unique and its type is string. I need to increment code field values by +1(code field is string).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `update_all` won't work because the record attributes are not available.

Better might be...

```
minimum = "15157"
maximum = "15160"

Item.where("code >= ? AND code <= ?", minimum, maximum).each{|i| i.update_attribute(:code, "#{i.code.to_i + 1}") }
```

(edited to reflect two arguments passed to `update_attribute`)

Edited to reflect @rustamagasanov suggestion to limit to a given range of code values...

Comment: they are available actually, because `update_all` works like a raw sql, but the main difficulty is to cast value to integer, then back to string in pg-syntax. In your code the main issue is that if he has a constraint on `code` field uniqueness - it won't work. Btw it's better to use `find_each`.

Comment: The above code is not working.I got following error:NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<Class:0x00560c80c0a688>

Comment: Hi, sorry, now changed to `Item.all.each` which should work for you.

Comment: @geethujoseph `Item.where("code >= ? AND code <= ?", 1111, 2222).find_each {}`

Comment: @geethujoseph `Item.where("code >= ? AND code <= ?", 1111, 2222).find_each { |i| i.update_attribute(:code, "#{i.code.to_i + 1}") }`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn,  Use the suggestion of RajarshiDas:  "#{i.code.to_i + 1}" instead of  "{i.code.to_i + 1}".

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Item.update_all(code: "#{code.to_i + 1}")
```

If you want to read [update_all](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all)

Comment: this is rails code using update_all method of Active Record relation for batch update

Comment: The above code is not working.I got the following error:NameError: undefined local variable or method `code' for main:Object